# Does caching interfer when server responses cookies to a GET request?

Tags: caching, cookies, get

I have a resource (an html web page, but it could be anything else like json/xml describing a book) and retrieve it with a `GET` request:

```
http://127.0.0.1/welcome
```

This resource is in Japanese (because kawai desu). Now, I do a `GET` request on this resource, asking server for another language:

```
http://127.0.0.1/welcome?lang=en
```

So the server responses with the English version of the resource. But from now on, since I called `?lang=en`, I want to set the default language of the user in a cookie. So server adds a cookie to its response:

```
Cookie: language=en
```

Browser now have the `language=en` cookie. Then, I ask for the resource without `GET` parameters and the server delivers the English version because the browser sent the `Cookie:language=en` request header:

```
http://127.0.0.1/welcome
```

Returns the English version.

---

- These queries look like retrieving (a resource with a cookie), idempotents (doesn't change a bit when send several times) and safe (server-modification less) queries to me: am I right to use `GET` requests even if they involve cookies?
- Two `GET` requests have the same URI `http://127.0.0.1/welcome`
  but different results: how does caching (browser and proxy) handle
  this?
- `GET` response for `http://127.0.0.1/welcome?lang=en` could be cached too: will (proxy/CDN, browser) cached responses include the `language=en` cookie (so user language for the website switches to en)?